# Npm package for Highchart Dumbell Chart

Tags: highcharts

Is there NPM package to install Highchart Dumbell chart ?, I checked on Highchart site and found that npm package for Highchart availble as : Highcharts 8.2.2 but not found for Dumbell Chart.

Answer (score 0):

The `dumbbell` series is a part of `highcharts` package, you just need to import and initialize it:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";

import dumbbell from "highcharts/modules/dumbbell";
dumbbell(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-z5s93